# Exclude a process from being listed in `top`

Tags: monitoring, performance-monitoring, process, top

Is it possible to exclude some processes from being reported by `top`?

For example, I would like to exclude itself from its listing (ie, I don't want `top` to show in the process list).

I would also like to be able to exclude processes that do not belong to the user running `top` (except for `root`).

Is this possible? If so, how? If not, is there a similar tool that will do what I want (that does not involve running something like `ps` frequently).

---

<sub><sup>I realize that you can monitor just a given user's processes by invoking with the `-u` or `-U` options, but that's not the same as monitoring *only* processes owned by the user running `top`.</sup></sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Top gets its information directly from the /proc filesystem which is "dummy" filesystem dynamically generated by the Linux kernel.

Therefore hiding specific processes (such as itself) is only possible if

1. You write a kernel module that hijacks the /proc fs
2. You modify the source code of top application (user level code)

If you want complete control over what is visible you should write a script/program yourself that reads /proc.

I suggest that you explore /proc a bit more. You might get away with a simple grep/cat/awk script that does what you want.

Comment: You can 'hide' processes in top if you can get the lookups in /proc to respond with EPERM. SELinux does this if you use certain specialist roles like 'user_u'. But I think what OP wants is a means to filter top.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather late to the conversation, but someone may find it useful. The OP want to view only the current user's processes and exclude `top` from the result. One could employ the `watch` command along with `top` and `grep`. For example:

```
watch -c -n 0.01 "top -b -U${USER} | grep -v -w -e top -e chrome -e libexec -e daemon -e csh"
```

Additional words to exclude can easily be added to `grep`.

Perhaps the `ps` output is preferred over `top`, since it may perform faster:

```
watch -c -n 0.01 "ps -aef | grep -w ${USER} | grep -v -w -e ps -e chrome -e libexec -e daemon -e csh"
```

For what it's worth, this is a different approach that requires neither a Linux kernel modification nor a modification of `top`'s source code.

***EDIT 2024-03-05:*** Here is a simple script that will invoke the `ps` command discussed above:

```
#!/bin/bash

#
# This is a simple wrapper for "watch"ing filtered "ps" output in an infinite loop. The ps table is too cluttered
# on a linux desktop -- this cleans it up according to a pre-defined FILTER.
#

FILTERED=(
 "-e ps"
 "-e chrome"
 "-e libexec"
 "-e daemon"
 "-e csh"
 "-e dbus"
 "-e gnome"
 "-e pulseaudio"
 "-e thunderbird"
 "-e ssh"
 "-e cat"
 "-e keybase"
 "-e slack"
 )

FILTER="grep -v -w ${FILTERED[@]}"

exec watch -c -n 0.01 "ps -aef | grep -w -e ${USER} -e PPID | ${FILTER}"
```

Answer (score -2):

top | grep -v  
gives that to some extent. But the display will get overlapped as the top refreshes.

Comment: Wrong. `grep` will run on _one_ round of `top` output only.

Comment: `top -n1` (in Linux) or `top -l1` (Mac OS X) will exit after sending just one iteration of output to STDOUT.